# Dual boot Windows 10 and Kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I installed kali linux next to windows 10. After the installation of linux, the system worked normally but when I started rebooting the computer GRUB disappeared, and only windows 10 turned on. Then I installed the EasyBCD program, but the effects were opposite to those intended. When the computer turns on, the windows boot manager pops up. Is it possible to remove the EasyBCD effect and restore GRUB?

computer:Lenovo ideapad 510 15ikb

EasyBCD effects:
[image]

[image]

(windows boot manager)

Comment: Have you tried changing the default boot manager in the EFI settings? Typically you get there by accessing the "BIOS" when booting by pressing some specific key; The key depends on the computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the instructions [here](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?20559-How-To-Repair-Kali-Linux-Grub-With-Kali-Linux-Live-Cd-Dual-Boot-With-Windows-7), it should solve your problem. Basically, the method is:

1. Boot the live cd.
2. chroot into the installed Kali partition after mount binding devices and special filesystems
3. Run `grub-install /dev/<kali device>` and `update-grub`

Alternatively, you could do the following:

1. Boot into the Kali installation. If you can from BCD good.  If not try to boot into it from the Kali install CD.
2. Run `grub-install /dev/<kali device>` and `update-grub`

Comment: Okay but i have 4 partition of Kali: /boot, /, /home and /swap so on which I should use this command?

Comment: @MateuszP, Please reference [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html). The command should be `grub-install /dev/<the disk drive that has Kali Linux on it>`